# Can't setup isc-dhcp-server in Windows 10 subsytem running Debian

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, isc-dhcpd

I am trying to setup a DHCP server in Windows subsystem for Linux running Debian. I have followed [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu/) as I am still quite new to the Linux scene. Although I did change some values in the `dhcpd.conf` file to fit my setup. Whenever I try to start the DHCP service it just spits out this error:
[image]

Here my `dhcpd.conf` file:
[image: dhcpd.conf file]

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the comment section of the link you posted? in Debian 9 they reported to need to call `/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable isc-dhcp-server` and then `systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server`

Comment: Not at first, but when you pointed it out I tried it. Still shows the same error.

Comment: hmm, now I will say I am largely out of my element with WSL but unless you are using WSL 2 (run `wsl -l -v` from powershell to find out your version, this only works _if_ you are running WSL 2) I believe you are using the Windows networking stack, or the [networking translation layers pointed out here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/11/08/225/). [WSL 2 runs a minified Hyper-V stack](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/) to create a more proper Linux virtual machine with far more control and should work like any other Linux VM on Hyper-V out there.

Comment: This means that DHCP, DNS, and the like are most likely handled by Windows so how to set that up for your WSL instance is out of scope for this site as this is a Unix and Linux stack exchange and not a Windows one.

Comment: I would also point out that your error wrote to syslog. You should investigate that to confirm exactly what is going wrong in your situation.

Comment: Turns out I'm running WSL. I tried looking for the syslog, but everywhere I looked it wasn't there... I tried running `sudo tail /var/log/syslog` when in root directory but I just get the error: `tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or directory`.

Comment: With `systemd` this is likely a file in `/var/log/journal`. Is there anything even located in `/var/log`? From a brief search I am finding that potentially you might not even have logging configured at all with a minimal Linux setup so you may need to enable that first.

Comment: In case of using systemd you should try using one of these two commands: `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server` or `journalctl -xe`

Comment: in short with WSL1 most tools using a SOCK_RAW socket will not work properly. Many things related to routing, crafting special packets etc. isc dhcpd (as well as dhclient) opens a SOCK_RAW socket.

Comment: It seems like there's also a problem with systemd because when I try to run `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server` or `systemctl start isc-dhcp-server` just get this error message returned: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`